# Javascript - display map using s57 (.000 file)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, maps, openlayers

I have a s57 `.000` file. I want to display it on a web page (with node and express).

1. How can I read the `.000` file and how to display it on a map?
2. Can I use any map? (Like leaflet.js or others)

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this project?

Answer (score 1):

One straightforward way to achieve this is to transform the S57 dataset into a different format - GeoJSON being a popular choice for maps in webpages.

There are several ways to perform this format conversion. I'm a fan of using the [`ogr2ogr` utility](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) for format conversions - and the [S57 format driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/s57.html) should be built-in in a OGR installation. [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/) should also be an option for people afraid of a command line. Others will probably recommend FME or other GIS packages.

Once the data is in GeoJSON format, displaying it in a wbpage map hould be easy - Leaflet, OpenLayers *et al* all have documentation about how to load and display data in GeoJSON format.